# How do I take a user off retention hold?

Tags: office365

[image]

Outlook says that a user is on Retention Hold, but I can't find where on the Office 365 portal to disable it - any ideas?

Comment: [**Retention hold**](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/08/office-365-common-confusion-around-email-retention-policies/) means the retention policies for the mailbox are currently disabled or "on hold". Take a step back and give us more detail so we can understand better. What issue are you trying to resolve that has lead you here? Is the user experiencing a problem?

Comment: The user is me - I have 3 Exchange emails on an Office 365 account and none of the others are on hold - i just wanted to understand where to go so that i could make the settings consistent across all three accounts -

Comment: What options are available when you click `Account Settings`? I believe you have to set this at the administrative level, not the user level. What are your options in the portal to email administration?

Comment: @CharlieRB - I have full admin access

Answer (score 1):

You can only remove this from PowerShell I believe.  I don't think there is anywhere in the User mailbox settings or ECP that gives you this option.

You would need to connect to Exchange Online via PowerShell, if you don't know how to do this and are not an admin - you should have an admin to help you with it (they would be the likely culprit for enabling it anyway).

To disable it you would run:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
#Connect to Exchange Online
$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $credential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $exchangeSession -AllowClobber

Set-Mailbox "William" -RetentionHoldEnabled $false
```

Comment: I'm the only admin on the account - I know how to connect via PowerShell, but I wouldn't have enabled this in the first place - could it have been enabled accidentally?  Otherwise there must be some place in the UI that I accidentally changed the settings...

Comment: I've not found it anywhere in the UI.  But I'd be interested to know when/if you do.  That being said - I have some instances where things like Org. configs were not right when MS generated the tenant, AND the new admin portal has been known to do weird things. For instance on one tenant, though they are synced, if you give them an Exchange license in new portal it creates a cloud mailbox regardless if they have on-prem mailbox and properties are correct on user object. MS has no answer to that, except to use old portal (it only happens for one customer - have not seen this anywhere else).

Answer (score 1):

When a .PST is imported to an online Exchange mailbox, it is automatically placed on retention hold. Presumably the hold is to prevent the retention policies in use from deleting message that may be outside the date range,thus giving the user some time to go through the emails first.

Comment: The OP wondered how to disable the retention hold.  Do you know if that is possible, and how to do it?